# Why parenthesis are needed when dereferencing a double pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have this function to delete the very first node in a single linked list:

```
void removeFront(Node **tmpHead){       
if ((*tmpHead)->next == NULL)
    cout << "Single Node! RemoveFront() aborted!\n";'
else{
Node *oldNode = *tmpHead;
*tmpHead = oldNode->next;
delete oldNode;     
}
```

}

Why do I need to put ***tmpHead** between brackets in the if statement? A compilation error is given if I don't.

Comment: Think about it like that if you don't put the parenthesis there, the compiler understand it as: `*(tmpHead->next)` and for the obvious reason that Node** does not have a member `next` it shows an error.

Comment: Because it's a `Node **`, not a `Node *`.

Comment: The `if` here is a distraction. The same issue arises any time you need to look at or change the contents of that `Node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*tmpHead->next` is interpreted as `*(tmpHead->next)`.

Since `tmpHead` is of type `Node**`, `tmpHead->next` is not a valid sub-expression.

That's why you need to use parenthesis around `*tmpHead` and use `(*tmpHead)->next == NULL`.